# Matching same string from different lists

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML structure consisting of:

A) a list of N-divs with classes such as the following:

```
<div class="classes">
   <div class="alpha">...</div>
   <div class="beta">....</div>
   <div class="gamma">.....</div>
   <div class="alpha beta">.....</div>
   <div class="alpha">....</div>
   <div class="beta gamma"></div>
   <div class="alpha beta gamma">.....</div>
   <div class="alpha">....</div>
   ....
</div>
```

B) A select populated with N-options containing a data attribute such as the following:

```
<select id="classSelect">
    <option value="something" data-class="alpha"></option>
    <option value="something-2" data-class="alpha"></option>
    <option value="something-3" data-class="beta"></option>
    <option value="something-4" data-class="alpha beta"></option>
    <option value="something-4" data-class="beta gamma"></option>
    ...
</select>
```

I want to achieve the following mechanism:

**A)** Find all the divs that have `class="alpha"`

**B)** Compare the divs string 'alpha' against every select option that has a data-attribute containing 'alpha'.

**C)** Disable or hide the options that do not contain the string.

So far i have figured that i need to: 1) Loop through every div with .alpha, 2)Get their classes, use .filter() to match the string with the data-attribute of all the options.

```
$('div.alpha').each(function() {
    var $item = $(this);
    var itemClasses = $item.attr('class');    
    $('#classSelect option').filter(function() { 
       *** CANT FIGURE OUT THIS PART ***
    });  
});
```

But I cant figure out the logic or the syntax of step B (mainly).

The output after the filtering should look like the following:

```
<select id="classSelect">
    <option value="something" data-class="alpha"></option>
    <option value="something-2" data-class="alpha"></option>
    <option value="something-3" data-class="beta" disabled></option>
    <option value="something-4" data-class="alpha beta"></option>
    <option value="something-4" data-class="beta gamma" disabled></option>
    ...
</select>

<div class="classes">
   <div class="alpha">...</div>
   <div class="beta">....</div>
   <div class="gamma">.....</div>
   <div class="alpha beta">.....</div>
   <div class="alpha">....</div>
   <div class="beta gamma"></div>
   <div class="alpha beta gamma">.....</div>
   <div class="alpha">....</div>
   ....
</div>
```

Can someone give me a hint with this?
Thank you for your time

Comment: The second step (B) isn't clear... can you explain more with examples? Cause divs are empty in your example

Comment: The inner content of the divs is irrelevant. It could be anything. The 'matching' must happen between the classes of the div and the data-attributes of the options in order to get to step C.

Comment: You want to match every div that has class 'alpha' or the ones that contain the 'alpha; class so `alpha beta gamma` would be good ? And why do you need to select the 'div.alpha' if you just want to hide the option that has data-class alpha

Comment: Contain, not exact match

Comment: to select elements that contain some string in attributes, try to use https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ this jquery selector

Comment: check my answer below. If i didn't understand correctly, please add a comment

Answer (score 0):

To select all the options that  have `data-class` which DO NOT contain some string ( in your case 'alpha' )  just do this. ( it can be done with css only, but i guess your final code will be more complex and that's why you want to use jQuery ). It can also be done with plain javaScript.

Not sure why you want to select the div's first. Maybe i didn't understand your requirements correctly.

```js
var options = $("#classSelect option")

$(options).each(function() {
 var dataClass = $(this).data('class')
  if ( !dataClass.includes('alpha')) {
   $(this).attr('disabled', true) // or hide() if you want to remove them
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classes">
   <div class="alpha">alpha</div>
   <div class="beta">beta</div>
   <div class="gamma">gamma</div>
   <div class="alpha beta">alpha beta</div>
   <div class="alpha">alpha</div>
   <div class="beta gamma">beta gamma</div>
   <div class="alpha beta gamma">alpha beta gamma</div>
   <div class="alpha">alpha</div>
</div>

<select id="classSelect">
    <option value="something" data-class="alpha">alpha</option>
    <option value="something-2" data-class="alpha">alpha</option>
    <option value="something-3" data-class="beta">beta</option>
    <option value="something-4" data-class="alpha beta">alpha beta</option>
    <option value="something-4" data-class="beta gamma">beta gamma</option>
</select>
```

OR you can just do this ( if you don't need to loop through the options for some other reason )

`$("#classSelect option").not("[data-class*='alpha']").attr('disabled',true)`